# How to get a previous value by reference in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I've reduced my actual code to give a more accurate example. Here's what I have:

```php
$result = [];
$entry = null;
$prev = null;

$arr = [1, 2, 3];

foreach ($arr as $val) {
    $entry = [
        'val' => $val,
        'children' => []
    ];

    if ($prev) {
        array_push($prev['children'], $entry);
    } else {
        array_push($result, $entry);
    }

    $prev = $entry;
}

var_dump($result);
```

When this code runs, it outputs this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["val"]=>
    int(1)
    ["children"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

My desired result is this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["val"]=>
    int(1)
    ["children"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["val"]=>
        int(2)
        ["children"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["val"]=>
            int(3)
            ["children"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this happens because on this line:

```php
$prev = $entry;
```

...the value of `$prev` is set to a *copy* of `$entry`. So in the next iteration when I push to `$prev['children']`, I mutate the copied array, not the original one that was pushed to `$result` in the first iteration.

I tried using a reference:

```php
$prev = &$entry;
```

...but I got the same result. Now, `$prev` is set to the contents of `$entry`, but when `$entry` is set to a new array in the next iteration, `$prev` points to that new array, instead of the previous one, which is useless.

---

I want `$prev` to point to the **contents** of `$entry` and not change on further mutations to the `$entry` variable. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes down to what is being pointed at each time.  You need to use references to allow it to add the new item to the correct point in the current structure, but the reference will be different depending on the first time or not.

The first time it needs to point the the `$result` field as this is where the end result is going, then it will be updated relative to itself, so that the entry keeps track of where it is...

```
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    $entry = [
            'val' => $val,
            'children' => []
    ];
    
    if ($prev) {
        $prev['children'] = $entry;
        $prev = &$prev['children'];
    } else {
        $result = $entry;
        $prev = &$result;
    }
    
}
```